# Transforming svg objects

Tags: css, svg

Why does this SVG code successfully rotate the left square but not the right?

```html
<svg id="work_window" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <defs>
        <style>
            #rectangle1 {
                fill: blue;
            }
            
            #rectangle2 {
                fill: blue;
                transform: rotate(30,0,10); <!-- scale here -->
            }
        </style>
        <rect id="rectangle1" height="10" width="10" transform="rotate(30,0,10)"/> <!-- scale here -->
        <rect id="rectangle2" height="10" width="10" />
    </defs>
    <use href="#rectangle1" x="20" y="10"/>
    <use href="#rectangle2" x="50" y="10"/>
</svg>
```

This is not an issue if you try a scale transform instead.

```html
<svg id="work_window" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <defs>
        <style>
            #rectangle1 {
                fill: blue;
            }
            
            #rectangle2 {
                fill: blue;
                transform: scale(2); <!-- scale here -->
            }
        </style>
        <rect id="rectangle1" height="10" width="10" transform="scale(2)"/> <!-- scale here -->
        <rect id="rectangle2" height="10" width="10" />
    </defs>
    <use href="#rectangle1" x="20" y="10"/>
    <use href="#rectangle2" x="50" y="10"/>
</svg>
```

I included the `fill` attribute as a test to see if objects placed by `use` couldn't be styled in this way, but the coloring was successful in both cases.

Comment: Be careful: native **SVG transform attributes and CSS transform properties are quite different**  – CSS rotations don't accept additional arguments for the **rotation origin** (... honestly, I prefer the svg concept). Besides, CSS transform values require units - most importantly `deg` for rotations. So  `rotate(30,0,10)`  will be ignored (check your element in DEV Tools). You can fix this e.g. by applying the "pivot point" first, then the rotation and eventually a negative translate like so:  `transform: translate(0px, 10px) rotate(30deg) translate(-0px, -10px)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the [SVG syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) in CSS, this won't work. The equivalent [CSS syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is

```css
transform: rotate(30deg);
transform-origin: 0 10px;
```

```html
<svg id="work_window" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <defs>
        <style>
            #rectangle1 {
                fill: blue;
            }
            
            #rectangle2 {
                fill: blue;
                transform: rotate(30deg);
                transform-origin: 0 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <rect id="rectangle1" height="10" width="10" transform="rotate(30,0,10)"/> <!-- scale here -->
        <rect id="rectangle2" height="10" width="10" />
    </defs>
    <use href="#rectangle1" x="20" y="10"/>
    <use href="#rectangle2" x="50" y="10"/>
</svg>
```